# Storing user data in Firebase database, on new user creation through authentication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble storing a new user's extra information (`displayName`, `firstName`, etc) in the database if and only if they have just created a new account.

signup function

```
var createAccount = function () {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword($("#email").val(), $("#password").val()).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
};
```

Is there a way to string a second function, that upon confirmation of a NEW user account, I then push all the extra data I have to the database?

As of now I am using `auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {...}` to check if a user is logged in or not to alter the navbar, which is on every page, but pushing new user data on this doesn't seem proper?

Thank you!